# How to register device token for Urban Airship SDK latest versions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

In the older versions of SDK we can register device token using below SDK delegate methods.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
   // Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
   [[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

But in the latest versions above delegate methods are removed so how to register device token in the latest SDK versions(ex:UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK - 9.0).

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the Airship SDK's automatic integration you will need to pass the SDK a few things like the device token you mentioned. Those methods for forwarding the details moved in [v8.0.0](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#version-800---september-7-2016) of the SDK. You access them with the `UAAppIntegration` class now like this:

```
[UAAppIntegration application:application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
```

This documentation should be up to date with more details: https://docs.airship.com/platform/ios/advanced/advanced-configuration/?obj-c#automatic-integration